# ProGuard: can't find referenced method 'javax.servlet.ServletConfig getServletConfig()'

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to configure ProGuard and I get the following error:

```
Warning:org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http.HttpTunnelingServlet: can't find referenced method 'javax.servlet.ServletConfig getServletConfig()' in program class org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http.HttpTunnelingServlet
```

I was trying to add these things, but none helped:

```
#-keep class javax.servlet.**
#-keep interface javax.servlet.**
#-keep class javax.servlet.ServletConfig { *; }
#-keep interface javax.servlet.ServletConfig { *; }
#-keepnames class * implements javax.servlet.ServletConfig { *; }
#-keep class * implements javax.servlet.ServletConfig { *; }
#-keep class * extends javax.servlet.ServletConfig { *; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ProGuard log probably also contains warnings about missing servlet classes. You should either add the servlet library (servlet.jar), or alternatively, you can probably tell ProGuard that it is ok that these classes are missing and as a result, that their methods are missing from the extension org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http.HttpTunnelingServlet:

```
-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.**
```

If these classes aren't used, it's better just not to include them in your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.**
```

add above code in your proguard-project.txt file